# Why does vlookup searche for `44221` instead of `2021-01-25`?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Q8 contains `2021-01-25` but the error says it looks for `44221`. Why?

[image]

Comment: You have only shown us part of the problem. We don't know what is in Col A, B or C. And we don't know the true format of anything. Consider sharing a link to the sheet, being sure to set the link's Share permission (when creating the link) to "Anyone with the link..." and "Editor."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spreadsheets, including Google Sheets, store dates as numbers. Dates can be shown in many different formats to the user, but their value is still just an integer.

More info: [here](https://www.excelcampus.com/functions/how-dates-work-in-excel/)

Note: if you want to convert the date to text, you can try
changing `C8:C&" "` to `to_text(C8:C)&" "` and see if that works?

Comment: Thanks, but the table I'm vlookuping in, has 2021-01-25 You, but it's not returned by the vlookup.

Comment: Try my suggestion in the post (edited) and see if that helps?

Answer (score 0):

This is because Google Sheets sees date as number of days since 31 of december 1899. When you see numbers 44 thousand and something, it's usually a date in number format.

I just checked - Vlookup N/A error message shows information in pure number format. BUt 44221 is an exact equivalent of 2021-01-25. So this is normal N/A error message. When this date is present as ID in table searched - it should work.

After second glance I see that you concatenate your vlookup and try to vlookup using 2 criteria. I am not sure if this table you search is correct.

I would rather use filter (or query) formula here:

```
=index(filter($C$8:$C;$A$8:$A=Q8;$B$8:$B=R8);1)
```

Filter formula in T8 displays content of column C where  Column A equals Q8 and column B equals R8. Index formula is used here to limit results to only first found value.